# How to remove Ubuntu to install Windows 7

Tags: 12.04

I had 12.04 installed but want to go back to Windows 7. After formatting my drive I am presented with the message `System not found` even when booting from a CD. I could not even reinstall Ubuntu with this error.

Comment: Bitte schreiben Sie ihre Frage auf Englisch. Please write your question in English.

Comment: You may have to change the boot order in BIOS.

Comment: mache ich ja jedesmal

Comment: Why Win7 now Win 8 is out! Why install an old OS?

Comment: daher ich nur win 7 habe und win 8 um die 100 euro kostet

Answer (score 0):

It is not customary or necessary to remove one operating sytem in order to make space for another. If you want to get rid of Ubuntu, you can just leave it on the disk and remove or  overwrite the partion from the Windows installation medium. The Windows installer will offer to overwrite anything, that it cannot handle more gracefully.

The same works vice versa, with the addition that Ubuntu also offers a nondestructive installation inside a Windows partition. Microsofts operating system is not that advanced, although the company would be free to make use of the necessary file system code from Linux.